# What is the best way to use fonts.googleapis.com in css files that are used in http and https pages?

Tags: css, http, https

I have a web-page that works correctly when its URL either starts with http:// or defaults to the http protocol when the protocol isn't specified, but errors with a message saying that the main.css file can't be found when the web-page's URL starts with http**s**://.

The latest version of Chrome's browser inspect console shows that the error occurs in the line that specifies the main.css stylesheet file:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/Resources/public/css/main.css" />
```

Using the Chrome inpect tool I found that two lines in the main.css file that import fonts from fonts.googleapis.com seem to be the issue because to their URLs start with http:// and cause Mixed Content errors so the browser blocks the main.css file.  Here are the lines:

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Alex+Brush);
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asul);
```

When I change these two URLs to start with http**s**:// the all of the errors go away when the page's URL starts with  http**s**:// or  http://.

**Question:**
Since my page is intended to be used in either protocol is there a way inside of the main.css file to use a script or some css mechanism to switch between http**s** and http protocols based on the protocol used by the page that links the main.css stylesheet? Say something like following pseudo-code:

```
  *IF protocol is https then*

    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Alex+Brush);
    @import url(http**s**://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asul);

  *ELSE*

    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Alex+Brush);
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asul);

  *ENDIF*
```

I say inside because I don't want to create two versions of the main.css file, one for each protocol, nor do I want to break out these lines into separate stylesheet files and somehow link those too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to load the fonts via http when https is available but simply emitting the protocol will work for you, as such just update to:

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Alex+Brush);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asul);
```